# Imaginary component of Dirichlet Eta Function's root with real component equal to 1/2

Tags: riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Let $$\space\space\space \eta(z) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{z}} \cdot (-1)^{a-1}  $$

Now let $\space$$z = \sigma + it $ ,

$$\eta(\sigma + it) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{\sigma + it}} \cdot (-1)^{a-1}  $$

May we split $\space\space$$\cfrac{1}{a^{\sigma + it}}$ $\space\space$ into its real and complex components:

$$\frac{1}{a^{\sigma + it}} = \frac{1}{a^{\sigma}} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{a^{it}}\right) = \frac{1}{a^{\sigma}} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{(e^{\ln{a}})^{it}}\right) = \frac{1}{a^{\sigma}} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{e^{(i\cdot t\ln{a})}}\right) = \frac{1}{{a^{\sigma}}} \cdot e^{-(i\cdot t\ln{a})}$$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$$ \qquad \qquad \quad = \frac{1}{{a^{\sigma}}} \cdot \bigg( \cos(-t\ln{a}) + i\cdot \sin(-t\ln{a}) \bigg) = \frac{1}{{a^{\sigma}}} \cdot \bigg( \cos(t\ln{a}) - i\cdot \sin(t\ln{a}) \bigg) $$

Therefore,

$$\space\space\space\Re \big(\eta(\sigma+it) \big) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{\sigma}}\cdot \cos(t\ln{a}) \cdot (-1)^{a-1}$$

$\\$

$$\Im \big(\eta(\sigma+it) \big) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{\sigma}}\cdot \sin(t\ln{a}) \cdot (-1)^{a} $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

Where $\Re$ and $\Im$ respectively represent the real and complex components of its argument.

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

For $z$ to be a root of $\eta$ we thus require that $\Re \big(\eta(z)\big) = 0 = \Im \big(\eta(z)\big) $.

Presumably there will be no such $z$ , with $\Re(z) = \sigma\neq \frac{1}{2} $ satisfying the condition above (for sure if Riemann Hypothesis turns to be true).

$ \\ $

So now I will focus on the numbers $z$, such that $\Re(z) = \frac{1}{2}$.

$ \\ $

Given that, the *unknown* of the problem will be $\space$ $t = \Im(z)$ $\space$ for which $\space$ $ \eta(\frac{1}{2} + it) = 0$.

Let me now reformulate what we're working on:

$ \\ $

$$ \eta(\tfrac{1}{2} + it) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{\frac{1}{2} + it}} \cdot (-1)^{a-1} $$

Which leads us to:

$ \\ $

$$ \space\space\space \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot \cos(t\ln{a}) \cdot (-1)^{a-1}$$

$ \\ $

and

$$ \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot \sin(t\ln{a}) \cdot (-1)^{a}$$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

Now letting $\space$ $a^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{a} $ $\space$, and writing it by extend:

$ \\ $

$$ \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{1}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{2}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{3}) - \dots $$

$ \\ $

$$ \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{1}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{2}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{3}) + \dots $$

$ \\ $

Onward,

$ \\ $

$$ \space \space \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big) \space = \space 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{2}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{3}) - \dots $$

$ \\ $

$$ \space \space \space \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big) \space = \space  0 \space + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{2}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{3}) + \dots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

For $\space$ $z = \frac{1}{2} + it$ $\space$ to be a root of $\eta$, we ought to require that:

$ \\ $

$$ \space \space 0 \space = \space 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{2}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{3}) - \dots $$

$ \\ $

$$ \space \space 0 \space = \space 0 \space + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{2}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{3}) + \dots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

$$\therefore$$

$ \\ $

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{2}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{3}) + \dots = 1 $$

$ \\ $

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{2}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{3}) + \dots = 0 $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

This system of equations doesn't look too alien, at least.

$ \\ $

Let's dive into the first equation, taken it's left side to be a function $f$ of $t$

$ \\ $

$$ f =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{2}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \cos(t\ln{3}) + \dots $$

$ \\ $

We will be then interested in finding the numbers $t$ for which $\space$ $f = 1$ $\space$ .

$ \\ $

Using the expansion

$$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \space \space \cdots \space \space (-1)^{j} \cdot \frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!} \space \space \cdots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
We can rewrite $f$ as

$ \\ $

$$ f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \bigg( 1 - \frac{(t\ln{2})^{2}}{2} + \frac{(t\ln{2})^{4}}{24} - \cdots \bigg) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \bigg( 1 - \frac{(t\ln{3})^{2}}{2} + \frac{(t\ln{3})^{4}}{24} - \cdots \bigg) + \cdots $$

$ \\ $

which we can reassemble to be written as a infinite polynomial in $t$:

$ \\ $

$$ f = \bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) - \frac{t^{2}}{2}  \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{2}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{2}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) + \frac{t^{4}}{24} \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{4}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{4}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg)-\cdots $$

$ \\ $

Now we've reached a remarkable point.

$ \\ $

The above polynomial's coefficients are no more than just constant numbers. And those numbers are pretty familiar.

$ \\ $

The independent coefficient,

$$\bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg)$$

is equal to

$$ 1 - \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}) \big)$$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

The quadratic coefficient,

$$ -\frac{1}{2}\bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{2}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{2}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) $$

is equal to

$$ -\frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{d^2 \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^2} \bigg) _{t=0} $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

And the quartic coefficient

$$ \frac{1}{24}\bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{4}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{4}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg)$$

is equal to

$$ \frac{1}{24} \bigg( - \frac{d^4 \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^4} \bigg) _{t=0} $$

$ \\ $

And so on with the subsequent coefficients.

$ \\ $

We can thus write $f$ as:

$ \\ $

$$ f = 1 - \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}) \big) + \frac{t^{2}}{2} \bigg( \frac{d^2 \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^2} \bigg) _{t=0} - \frac{t^{4}}{24} \bigg(\frac{d^4 \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^4} \bigg) _{t=0} + \cdots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

If we want $f = 1$, then $t$ must be the roots of $\space$ $\beth$ $\space$, where

$ \\ $

$$ \beth = \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}) \big) - \frac{t^{2}}{2} \bigg( \frac{d^2 \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^2} \bigg) _{t=0} + \frac{t^{4}}{24} \bigg(\frac{d^4 \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^4} \bigg) _{t=0} - \cdots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

Compactly written as

$ \\ $

$$ \beth = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{l} \cdot \frac{t^{2l}}{(2l)!} \cdot \bigg( \frac{d^{(2l)} \Re \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^{(2l)}} \bigg) _{t=0}$$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

Let's go through an analogous procedure now with the second of our two main equations.

$ \\ $

First, taken it's left side to be a function $g$ of $t$

$ \\ $

$$ g =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{2}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \sin(t\ln{3}) + \dots $$

$ \\ $

We will be then interested in finding the numbers $t$ for which $\space$ $g = 0$ $\space$ .

$ \\ $

Using the expansion

$$\sin(x) =  x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \space \space \cdots \space \space (-1)^{j} \cdot \frac{x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!} \space \space \cdots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
We can rewrite $g$ as

$ \\ $

$$ g = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \bigg( (t\ln{2}) - \frac{(t\ln{2})^{3}}{6} + \frac{(t\ln{2})^{5}}{120} \cdots \bigg) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \bigg( (t\ln{3}) - \frac{(t\ln{3})^{3}}{6} + \frac{(t\ln{3})^{5}}{120} \cdots \bigg) + \cdots $$

$ \\ $

which we can reassemble to be written as an infinite polynomial in $t$:

$ \\ $

$$ g = t \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) - \frac{t^{3}}{6}  \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{3}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{3}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) + \frac{t^{5}}{120} \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{5}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{5}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg)$$

$ \\ $

$$ - \cdots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

Those polynomial's coefficients are also familiar.

$ \\ $

The linear coefficient,

$$ \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) $$

is equal to

$$ \bigg( \frac{d \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt} \bigg) _{t=0} $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

The cubic coefficient,

$$ - \frac{1}{6} \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{3}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{3}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) $$

is equal to

$$ \frac{1}{6} \bigg( \frac{d^3 \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^3} \bigg) _{t=0} $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

And the quintic coefficient,

$$  \frac{1}{120} \bigg( \frac{(\ln{2})^{5}}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{(\ln{3})^{5}}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots \bigg) $$

is equal to

$$ \frac{1}{120} \bigg( \frac{d^5 \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^5} \bigg) _{t=0} $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

So on with the subsequent coefficients we can write $g$ as:

$ \\ $

$$ g =  t \bigg( \frac{d \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt} \bigg) _{t=0} + \frac{t^{3}}{6} \bigg(\frac{d^3 \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^3} \bigg) _{t=0} + \frac{t^{5}}{120} \bigg(\frac{d^5 \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^5} \bigg) _{t=0} + \cdots $$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $

As we want $g = 0$, then $t$ must be the roots of $\space$ $\gimel$ $\space$, where

$ \\ $

$$ \gimel = t \bigg( \frac{d \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt} \bigg) _{t=0} + \frac{t^{3}}{6} \bigg(\frac{d^3 \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^3} \bigg) _{t=0} + \frac{t^{5}}{120} \bigg(\frac{d^5 \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^5} \bigg) _{t=0} + \cdots $$

$ \\ $

Compactly written as

$ \\ $

$$ \gimel = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2l+1}}{(2l+1)!} \cdot \bigg( \frac{d^{(2l+1)} \Im \big(\eta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it) \big)}{dt^{(2l+1)}} \bigg) _{t=0}$$

$ \\ $
$ \\ $
$ \\ $

So far this is the most explicit representation of $t$, which is the imaginary component of a non-trivial root of $\eta$(or $\zeta$), I could reach.

$ \\ $
To partially conclude this post, and to state what has been accomplished: 
$ \\ $
$ \\ $
There are two infinite polynomials, $\beth$ and $\gimel$, defined as mentioned, such that their common roots happen to be the imaginary component of the (some, probably all) non-trivial roots of the Riemann Zeta function.

$ \\ $

$ \\ $

I'd like to thank you if you went along all through this point, and to say that any comments or suggestions will be greatly welcomed.

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: It’s not a specific question, indeed. If I’d to put in more directly it would be : “How can we find a closed formula for the non-trivial roots of the Riemann Zeta function, given that it has real part equal to 0.5”. By doing so, I expect some ideias on how to prove (or disprove) the Riemann Hypothesis will be obtained.

Comment: I recall when I was a student, I also attempted to break zeta function into real and imaginary parts, and then tried to prove/disprove RH. I didn’t know derivatives so what you have done is surely more advanced. However, I somehow think that the series you established are simply some taylor series. Moreover, the rearrangements of sums are not always permitted; I didn’t check validity, but the validity surely depends on the type of convergence of zeta/eta function.

Comment: My first thoughts were to split Zeta into real and imaginary, too. Though I found out that it wouldn't be very useful, since the Zeta function (the simple one) does not converge for Re(z) < 1. As I wanted to investigate Re(z) = 1/2, the Dirichlet Eta function turned out to be better to work on.  Let me know if you find incorrectness among my work done so far.

Comment: At the moment I don’t have the time. I may be will check later. By the way, I suggest you to rewrite your question more compactly so that the question won’t be too long; I am sure that many users lost interest due to its length.